# toString() method for my linked list only prints the first element

Tags: java

I'm implementing my own java.util.linkedlist from scratch so I'm not using any of the java.util.linkedlist capabilities. That being said, I'm currently trying to create my own toString method. This is my node class

```
private static class Node<T>{ 

  private T data; 
  private Node<T> next; 

  public Node(T d){ 
     next= null; 
     data = d; 
  }

  public Node(T d, Node<T> n){
     data = d; 
     next = n; 
  }

  public T getData(){ 
     return data; 
  }

  public void setData(T d){ 
     data = d; 
  }

  public Node<T> getNext(){ 
     return next; 
  }

  public void setNext(Node<T> n){ 
     next = n; 
  }
}
```

and this is my listclass

```
  private Node<T> start;
  private int size; 
  public ListNoOrder() {
  start = null; 
  size = 0;  
}

public void add(T newElt) {

  Node<T> temp = new Node<T>(newElt); 
  Node<T> current = start; 

  try{ if (newElt==(null));}
  catch (Exception illegalArgumentException){
     throw new IllegalArgumentException();}

  if (start == null){ 
     start = new Node<T>(newElt, null); 
  }

  if(current != null){ 
     while (current.next != null){ 
        current.setNext(temp); 
     }
  }
  size++; 
}

public int length() {
   return size;}
```

and my toString method so far

```
 public String toString() {
  String toPrint = ""; 
  Node <T> current = start; 

  while (current != null){ 
     toPrint += current.getData(); 
     if (current.next != null)
        toPrint += " ,"; 
     current = current.getNext(); 
  }
 return toPrint; 
}
```

when I test the method it only prints the first element of the list.

mockList = 7, 8, 15, 62, 38, 3 
whatItsPrinting = 7,

I've been struggling for hours.

Comment: add code of initialization of your list (the place where you are adding elements and calling toString method). Also **Where is toString method defined**? It seems that it has access to private `next` Node field?

Comment: Something tells me `start` is actually the last node of your chain

Comment: What do you mean where is toString defined? @m.antkowicz

Comment: I'm implementing a singly linked list @AxelH ...how would i fix it?

Comment: is it in `Node<T>` class or in `ListNoOrder` class?

Comment: @m.antkowicz it's in the ListNoOrder class

Comment: So how the heck it has access to private `next` Node field? I mean in this line `if (current.next != null)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `add` method you are setting just `start` variable at the beginning here

```
start = new Node<T>(newElt, null);
```

but you never set next nodes because `next` of `start` is *null* so the following condition is never true

```
if(current != null){ 
    while (current.next != null){  // this one!
        current.setNext(temp); 
    }
}
```

Even if this condition would be true it would not really worked - what you need to do here is to get the **last** node (node without `next` and to set only it's `next`). Something like

```
if(current != null) {
    while(current.getNext() != null) {
        current = current.getNext();
    }
    current.setNext(new Node<T>(newElt));
}
else {
    current = new Node<T>(newElt, null); // because current is start
}
```

Comment: ohhh I see...how would I set next nodes then?

Comment: thank you thank you thank you...I'm new to data structures just trying to get the hang of it! thank you. @m.antkowicz

Comment: glad to help ;)